# LM4040 pinout not matching reality vs datasheet

Tags: pinout, voltage-reference

I bought some voltage references from the `LM4040` family, `NFC41I` and `NFC20I` i.e. `4.096V` and `2.048V` respectively, all TO-92 packages.

The [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm4040.pdf) only shows these two pinouts:

[image: pinouts screenshot]

And then, near the end, a numbering of pins for the TO-92 package:

[image: TO-92 numbering]

However, I couldn't get it to work, and after trying all possible connections, turns out that cathode (power/output) is center pin (2), while anode (GND) is the right (looking at the flat "face") pin (1). It doesn't match any of the previous pinouts.

What is going on? Where am I wrong?

Comment: The datashet provides no pinout for that package, so nobody's wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  You can find the old datasheet [here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/8903/NSC/LM4040.html)

It shows the following:

[image]

Since the TO-92 is a very old package, the correct pinout information probably fell off the datasheet during an update and nobody has corrected it yet.

Comment: Ah, didn't think that such a company could forget or accidentally remove something. Should've googled precisely for the TO92 package...

Comment: @herhor67 Have you submitted documentation feedback to tell them the TO-92 pinout is missing?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Did not know that's possible. I just did. Thank you.